# Multiple pagination on one page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i am new in ruby and rails 4 .

I am trying to do multiple pagination in one page using kaminari gem .

I created service page where i am showing different services,departments in a horizontal tab menu i have three options in my tab menu .

When i click on tabs its shows its details along with its pagination details. Now the problem is that the pagination works only when I double click on the pagination links.

Can anybody help me what is going wrong in my code :-

In service controller :-

```
def index

 if params[:search]
        @search_state_services=Service.where('sname LIKE ? AND scategory = ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", '2').page(params[:page]).order(:sname)
        @search_nat_services=Service.where('sname LIKE ? AND scategory = ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", '1').page(params[:page]).order(:sname)
        @search_servic_services=Service.where('sname LIKE ? AND scategory = ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", '3').page(params[:page]).order(:sname)
else
    @nat_services=Service.where(scategory: 1).page(params[:page]).order(:sname)
    @state_services=Service.where(scategory: 2).page(params[:page]).order(:sname)
    @servic_services=Service.where(scategory: 3).page(params[:page]).order(:sname)
    @services = Service.page(params[:page]).order(:sname)
end
respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.js
      end
```

In index view:-

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#national">National</a></li>
<li><a href="#state">State</a></li>
<li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>

</ul>

<div id="content">
     <div id="national" class="tab-section">

       <p>
         <%= render 'nat1' %>
       </p>
     </div>
       <div id="state" class="tab-section2">

        <p>
        <%= render 'state1' %>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div id="services" class="tab-section">
       </div>
</div>
    <script >
        $(function() {
                    $('#tabs').find('a').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this.hash).show().siblings().hide();
                        }).filter(':first').click();
                    });

    </script>
```

In nat1:-

```
<h2  style="border-bottom:0px;color:black;">
<a name="t1" id="t1">National </a>
</h2>

<% @nat_services.each do |nservice|    %>                                                           
<div style="display:inline-block;"> 
    <p style="background:lightgrey; padding-top: 5px;padding-right: 5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left: 5px;">
        <%= link_to "#{nservice.sname}", service_path(nservice.id) %>
    </p>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="nat_1" style="text-align:center;color:black;">
<%= paginate @nat_services, :remote => true %>                                                                      
</div>
```

In index js :-

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('div.nat_1').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('div#national').html('<%= escape_javascript render 'nat1' %>');

       $('.nat_1').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@nat_services,     :remote    => true).to_s) %>');


     return false;

    });

  $('div.state_1').bind('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('div#state').html('<%= escape_javascript render 'state1' %>');
    $('.state_1').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@state_services,    :remote => true).to_s) %>');

  });

  });
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know why you have to double click the links, but you may consider using different params for pagination for each elements. And, what's most important - your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection in your where statements, please refer here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html to secure your application

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please advise as to how I can use different params for each element based on above code ?

Comment: to use different params for each pagination, in your view add params_name to paginate, like: `<%= paginate @users, :param_name => :pagina %>` and use this param_name in controller